# Why won't Mathematica Solve a set of two equations for one variable?

Tags: equation-solving

For example, if I try to Solve this set of equations

```
Solve[y == 3 x + 5 && y == -x + 7, {x, y}]
```

Mathematica gives the right values for `x` and `y`. But if I try

```
Solve[y == 3 x + 5 && y == -x + 7, {x}]
```

it returns nothing. Why is that? There doesn't seem to be a mathematical reason for it.

Comment: Use MaxExtraConditions->Infinity (or even just 1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That syntax makes Mathematica assume that `y` can be anything, and if `y` is different from 13/2, then there's no `x`, so it can't solve it for the general case.

In other words, `Solve` must return results that satisfy the equalities. Replacing `x` by 1/2, the solution you're looking for, doesn't make the equalities be true. For them to be true, you need to solve for `y` also

EDIT

It seems `Solve`'s third argument also serves as a list of variables to eliminate. So, you should do

```
Solve[y == 3 x + 5 && y == -x + 7, {x}, {y}]
```

> {{x -> 1/2}}

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer. But couldn't it return a conditional expression then: `ConditionalExpression[1/2, y=13/2]`? Too far-fetched? Also, it knows `y` isn't assigned.

Comment: @stevenvh `ConditionalExpression` doesn't fit here. If we replaced `x->ConditionalExpression[1/2, y==13/2]`, the equality would turn into something like `ConditionalExpression[y==13/2, y==13/2]`, which is not `True`. There's nothing I can think of that you can put in place of `x` (that doesn't assign `y` an actual value) that would render the equation `True`. However, I see your point and your intentions. What you want is perhaps more suited for `Reduce`'s spirit I think. This is not my strong area so if you are not satisfied, be hopeful and wait for other answers

Comment: `ConditionalExpression[y==13/2, y==13/2]` is not true??

Comment: @stevenvh it's as much true as `If[x == True, True]`. The condition is a prerrequisite, not an assumption

Comment: @stevenvh You'll get `{x -> ConditionalExpression[1/2, y == 13/2]}` using this `MaxExtraConditions->All` option in `Solve`.

Comment: @stevenvh, check the edit

Comment: Pretty much what I said in the comment to Jens's answer... :D

Comment: @J.M. - Your own fault, you should have posted as an answer :-). I never thought of using {y} as domain argument for Solve, but I like it better than nesting an Eliminate inside a Solve. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @steven: I'd have posted it if Jens hadn't posted his longer version. I'll note that that form for `Solve[]` has always been supported in *Mathematica*: `Solve[eqns, vars, elims]`, that is, solve for variables in `vars` in `eqns`, while eliminating variables in `elims`.

Comment: @J.M would you believe me I just read it in the Solve tutorial? :P

Comment: I could, Rojo. I could. ;P

Comment: @Rojo, J.M.: I can't find any documentation on using {y} as domain argument for Solve nor on the version `Solve[eqns, vars, elims]`. Can you tell me where to find it?

Comment: I can't remember now nor have time to look but, it seems the Rojo of the past (look up  a couple of comments) saw it in the Solve tutorial in the docs

Answer (score 10):

`Solve` works directly with `MaxExtraConditions` (new in `Mathematica 8`) option set `All` or `1` :

```
Solve[y == 3 x + 5 && y == -x + 7, x, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

> ```
> {{x -> ConditionalExpression[1/2, y == 13/2]}}
> ```

or solving with respect to `y` :

```
Solve[ y == 3 x + 5 && y == -x + 7, {y}, MaxExtraConditions -> 1]
```

> ```
> {{y -> ConditionalExpression[13/2, x == 1/2]}}
> ```

`ConditionalExpression` is also new in `M8`.

In another case one has to use `Eliminate` :

```
Eliminate[ y == 3 x + 5 && y == -x + 7, {#}] & /@ {x, y}
```

> ```
> {2 y == 13, 2 x == 1}
> ```

However using `Reduce` (it is more universal) there is no need for elimination of variables or using any options :

```
Reduce[y == 3 x + 5 && y == -x + 7, x]
```

> ```
> y == 13/2 && x == 1/2
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You might have guessed that the example wasn't my real problem :-), and eliminating `y` like in your Solve example is no option. It's a set of 3 equations with 7 variables in $\mathbb{C}$, so I'm not going to eliminate by hand :-).

Comment: @stevenvh Anyway `MaxExtraConditions` in `Solve` or `Reduce` without any option satisfies your needs I hope, as you can read from the answer.

Comment: Nice one! I had no idea of that option +1

Comment: Very useful (+1)

Comment: Rojo and Jens, Thank You !

Comment: @stevenvh A related problem you can find here : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7796/solving-for-one-solution-to-a-system-of-polynomials/7798#7798

Comment: @Artes - Yes, I saw it too. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
Solve[Eliminate[y == 3 x + 5 && y == -x + 7, y], x]

(* ==> {{x -> 1/2}} *)
```

I first tell Mathematica to reduce the two equations to one by eliminating the variable I don't want to solve for (`y`), and then solve for the remaining one, `x`.

Comment: More compactly: `Solve[y == 3 x + 5 && y == -x + 7, {x}, {y}]`.