# solving for one solution to a system of polynomials

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I'm trying to solve a system of equations:

```
Solve[ A1 D1 + E1 H1 == 0 && A2 D1 + A1 D2 + E2 H1 + E1 H2 == 0 &&
       C1 F1 - E1 G1 == 0 && C2 F2 - E2 G2 == 0 && A1 - B1 + C1 == 0 &&
        A2 - B2 + C2 == 0 &&  A3 - B3 + C3 == 0,      
       {A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3,D1,D2,E1,E2,F1,F2,G1,G2,H1,H2}]
```

Since we have more variables than equations, we have more than 1 solution satisfying the above equations but I don't want Mathematica to give me all possible solutions -- I would like just only one.

**1. How do I get Mathematica to give me just one possible solution?**

One way I thought about doing this is to plug in random numbers such as `A2 = 1/2, B2 = 1, C2 = 1/2`, etc. so that all other variables are determined. But this isn't a very effective strategy in case the numbers I plug in do not satisfy all of the above equations.

(One reason why I don't want all possible solutions to a system of equations is because suppose I am working with 30 equations and 80 variables. Then this is crashing Mathematica.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindInstance.html) :

```
FindInstance[A1 D1 + E1 H1 == 0 && A2 D1 + A1 D2 + E2 H1 + E1 H2 == 0 && 
  C1 F1 - E1 G1 == 0 && C2 F2 - E2 G2 == 0 && A1 - B1 + C1 == 0 && 
  A2 - B2 + C2 == 0 && A3 - B3 + C3 == 0, 
  {A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1,C2, C3, D1, D2, E1, E2, F1, F2, G1, G2, H1, H2}]

(* {{A1 -> 0, A2 -> 0, A3 -> 0, B1 -> 0, B2 -> 0, B3 -> 0, C1 -> 0, 
     C2 -> 0, C3 -> 0, D1 -> 0, D2 -> 0, E1 -> 0, E2 -> 0, F1 -> 0, 
     F2 -> 0, G1 -> 0, G2 -> 0, H1 -> 0, H2 -> 0}} *)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! It worked!! =)

Comment: @math-visitor Have a look at `Reduce`, it might suit your needs better.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely try that!

Comment: @math-visitor My answer make use of `Solve` and can help you to choose any solution you want.

Answer (score 5):

**FindInstance**

`FindInstance[eqns,vars]` gives you only a trivial solution (`A1 == A2 == ...== H2 == 0`), which is not what one reallly wants. `FindInstance[eqns, vars, n]` helps in finding `n` solutions, e.g. for `n == 2` yields  two non-trivial solutions :

```
FindInstance[ A1 D1 + E1 H1 == 0 && A2 D1 + A1 D2 + E2 H1 + E1 H2 == 0 && 
              C1 F1 - E1 G1 == 0 && C2 F2 - E2 G2 == 0 && A1 - B1 + C1 == 0 &&
              A2 - B2 + C2 == 0 && A3 - B3 + C3 == 0,
             {A1, A2, A3, B1, B2,  B3, C1, C2, C3, D1, D2, E1, E2, F1, F2, G1, G2, H1, H2}, 2]
```

Of course **there are infinitely many** such instances of solutions, so they aren't too interesting as well.

What one really would like is a **symbolic solution**. Thus one should make use of `Solve` or `Reduce`.

**Solve**

Working with `Solve` you can find **what and how many symbolic solutions there are**   adding this option `MaxExtraConditions -> All`  :

```
sols = Solve[ A1 D1 + E1 H1 == 0 && A2 D1 + A1 D2 + E2 H1 + E1 H2 == 0 && 
              C1 F1 - E1 G1 == 0 && C2 F2 - E2 G2 == 0 && A1 - B1 + C1 == 0 && 
               A2 - B2 + C2 == 0 && A3 - B3 + C3 == 0, 
             {A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3, D1, D2, E1, E2, F1, F2, G1, G2, H1, H2}, 
             MaxExtraConditions -> All] // Quiet;
```

so you can check how many solutions there are :

```
Length @ sols
```

> ```
> 27
> ```

and select `n-k` solutions, for `1 <= k < n <= 27` :  `sols[[ k;;n ]]`, e.g. the first one

```
sols[[1]]
```

> ```
>  {B1 -> ConditionalExpression[A1 + C1, E1 != 0 && E2 != 0 && A1 D1 != 0], 
>   B2 -> ConditionalExpression[A2 + C2, E1 != 0 && E2 != 0 && A1 D1 != 0], 
>   C3 -> ConditionalExpression[-A3 + B3, E1 != 0 && E2 != 0 && A1 D1 != 0], 
>   G1 -> ConditionalExpression[(C1 F1)/E1, E1 != 0 && E2 != 0 && A1 D1 != 0], 
>   G2 -> ConditionalExpression[(C2 F2)/E2, E1 != 0 && E2 != 0 && A1 D1 != 0], 
>   H1 -> ConditionalExpression[-((A1 D1)/E1), E1 != 0 && E2 != 0 && A1 D1 != 0], 
>   H2 -> ConditionalExpression[-((A2 D1 + A1 D2 - (A1 D1 E2)/E1)/E1),
>                                E1 != 0 && E2 != 0 && A1 D1 != 0]}
> ```

this means e.g. that `B1 == A1 + C1` under conditions `E1 != 0 && E2 != 0 && A1 D1 != 0`.

One can observe that if we omit `MaxExtraConditions` or we add `MaxExtraConditions -> Automatic` then solutions will not be represented in terms of `ConditionalExpressions` and therefore some troubles can apear potentially.

Sometimes it will be handy to specify  **only a few variables**. Then we can use also `MaxExtraConditions` in `Solve`, and specifying   e.g. `{A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3}` we get **only one symbolic solution** :

```
Solve[ A1 D1 + E1 H1 == 0 && A2 D1 + A1 D2 + E2 H1 + E1 H2 == 0 && C1 F1 - E1 G1 ==0 &&
       C2 F2 - E2 G2 == 0 && A1 - B1 + C1 == 0 && A2 - B2 + C2 == 0 && A3 - B3 + C3 == 0, 
      {A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3}, MaxExtraConditions -> Automatic] // Quiet
```

> ```
> {{A1 -> ConditionalExpression[-((E1 H1)/D1), F2 == (E2 G2)/C2 && F1 == (E1 G1)/C1], 
>   A2 -> ConditionalExpression[((D2 E1 H1)/D1 - E2 H1 - E1 H2)/D1, 
>                                F2 == (E2 G2)/C2 && F1 == (E1 G1)/C1], 
>   B1 -> ConditionalExpression[C1 - (E1 H1)/D1, F2 == (E2 G2)/C2 && F1 == (E1 G1)/C1], 
>   B2 -> ConditionalExpression[C2 + ((D2 E1 H1)/D1 - E2 H1 - E1 H2)/D1, 
>                                F2 == (E2 G2)/C2 && F1 == (E1 G1)/C1], 
>   B3 -> ConditionalExpression[A3 + C3,  F2 == (E2 G2)/C2 && F1 == (E1 G1)/C1]}}
> ```

**Reduce**

`Reduce` finds all solutions

```
r = Reduce[ A1 D1 + E1 H1 == 0 && A2 D1 + A1 D2 + E2 H1 + E1 H2 == 0 && 
            C1 F1 - E1 G1 == 0 && C2 F2 - E2 G2 == 0 && A1 - B1 + C1 == 0 && 
            A2 - B2 + C2 == 0 && A3 - B3 + C3 == 0, 
            {A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3, D1, D2, E1, E2, F1, F2, G1, G2, H1, H2}];
```

being implicitly `ConditionalExpression`'s.  To select only one solution we just evaluate  `r[[n]]` for `1<= n <= 25`.

**Warning**

Comparing with `sols`, found by `Solve` the number of solutions may be slightly different
because certain `ConditionalExpression`'s repeat some identical solutions under different conditions :

```
Length @ r
```

> ```
> 25
> ```

Comment: Wow.... this definitely helps. Thank you Artes!

Comment: @math-visitor I'm glad I could help.